# How to prove closure of $(\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$?

Tags: group-theory

We're told $(\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\},\cdot)$ is abelian in a lemma in my algebraic structures notes. I just tried to prove it while I was reading through but it's taken me way too long.

How do I show that for $a,b \in \Bbb Z_p$, $p$ is not a divisor of their product ($p$ prime)

Comment: This is Gauss'lemma, if a prime $p$ divides the product $ab$ of two numbers $a$ and $b$ then $p$ must divide $a$ or $b$. By contre-apposition if $p$ does not divide $a$ and does not divide $b$ then $p$ won't divide $ab$.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin That result predates Gauss by two millennia. It's called Euclid's lemma. Still, it's the right one to use.

Comment: This is basically the uniqueness of prime factorization: a product $kp$ cannot be written as $ab$ for $a,b<p$. A simple proof is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic#Elementary_proof_of_uniqueness

Comment: @Arthur, Thanks for the correction, unfortunately I cannot correct this, of course the result was known way before Gauss^^.

Answer (score 0):

By Gauss' Lemma on a property of primes, if $p\mid ab$, then either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. (Why?)

*Hint:*

> Use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Now the contrapositive states that if *both $p\nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$*, then $p\nmid ab$.